# Create new variables like `BASE_URL` to use in index.html with vue-ci-service

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli-service to build a vue app and need to define things like a (not secret) api key - say for Google Maps.

In index.html I see: `<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">`

I'd like to be able to create my own variables like GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY and have a different value based on Node's `development` or `production` mode.

I tried `.env.development` and `.env.production` files, but I think those are to set VUE environment variables and it's "too late" in the process to render them in the template. I get an error:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  ReferenceError: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY is not defined
  
  - index.html:8 eval
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:8:11
```

How do I inject values from an .env (or other key/value) file into my templates like the BASE_URL - I would like to have a file for each Node `mode` := `development` | `production`

I would like to have this in my index.html file:

```
 <script
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY %>&libraries=&v=weekly"
          defer
  ></script>
```

How do I do this? I'm not interested in dynamically loading the Javascript at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.env.development` & `.env.production` can do that - you just have to pay attention to start your variables with **VUE_APP_**, like `VUE_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`.

> Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and **variables that start with
> VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle** with
> webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private
> key on the machine that could have the same name.

*Source: [vuejs.org](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)*